# MySQL - subquery sorting MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    post_type, post_status, 
    COUNT(post_id) AS posts, 
    SUM(post_word_count) AS word_count, 
    SUM(post_tag_p_count) AS text_p_count, 
    SUM(post_text_p_length) AS text_p_length, 
    MAX(post_text_p_length) AS max_text_p_length, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(post_text_p_length) 
        FROM $table_name_posts 
        WHERE post_text_p_length !=''
    ) AS min_text_p_length, 
    SUM(post_text_p_length_characters_without_spaces) AS text_p_length_characters_without_spaces, 
    MAX(post_text_p_length_characters_without_spaces) AS max_text_p_length_characters_without_spaces, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(post_text_p_length_characters_without_spaces) 
        FROM $table_name_posts 
        WHERE post_text_p_length_characters_without_spaces !=''
    ) AS min_text_p_length_characters_without_spaces, 
    SUM(post_text_p_length_characters) AS text_p_length_characters, 
    MAX(post_text_p_length_characters) AS max_text_p_length_characters, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(post_text_p_length_characters) 
        FROM $table_name_posts 
        WHERE post_text_p_length_characters !=''
    ) AS min_text_p_length_characters, 
    SUM(post_tag_h1_count) AS text_h1_count, 
    SUM(post_text_h1_length) AS text_h1_length, 
    MAX(post_text_h1_length) AS max_text_h1_length, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(post_text_h1_length) 
        FROM $table_name_posts 
        WHERE post_text_h1_length !=''
    ) AS min_text_h1_length, 
    SUM(post_text_h1_length_characters_without_spaces) AS text_h1_length_characters_without_spaces, 
    MAX(post_text_h1_length_characters_without_spaces) AS max_text_h1_length_characters_without_spaces, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(post_text_h1_length_characters_without_spaces) 
        FROM $table_name_posts 
        WHERE post_text_h1_length_characters_without_spaces !=''
    ) AS min_text_h1_length_characters_without_spaces, 
    SUM(post_text_h1_length_characters) AS text_h1_length_characters, 
    MAX(post_text_h1_length_characters) AS max_text_h1_length_characters, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(post_text_h1_length_characters) 
        FROM $table_name_posts 
        WHERE post_text_h1_length_characters !=''
    ) AS min_text_h1_length_characters, 
    SUM(post_tag_h2_count) AS text_h2_count, 
    SUM(post_text_h2_length) AS text_h2_length, 
    MAX(post_text_h2_length) AS max_text_h2_length, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(post_text_h2_length) 
        FROM $table_name_posts 
        WHERE post_text_h2_length !=''
    ) AS min_text_h2_length, 
    SUM(post_text_h2_length_characters_without_spaces) AS text_h2_length_characters_without_spaces, 
    MAX(post_text_h2_length_characters_without_spaces) AS max_text_h2_length_characters_without_spaces, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(post_text_h2_length_characters_without_spaces) 
        FROM $table_name_posts 
        WHERE post_text_h2_length_characters_without_spaces !=''
    ) AS min_text_h2_length_characters_without_spaces, 
    SUM(post_text_h2_length_characters) AS text_h2_length_characters, 
    MAX(post_text_h2_length_characters) AS max_text_h2_length_characters, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(post_text_h2_length_characters) 
        FROM $table_name_posts 
        WHERE post_text_h2_length_characters !=''
    ) AS min_text_h2_length_characters, 
    SUM(post_tag_h3_count) AS text_h3_count, 
    SUM(post_text_h3_length) AS text_h3_length, 
    MAX(post_text_h3_length) AS max_text_h3_length, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(post_text_h3_length) 
        FROM $table_name_posts 
        WHERE post_text_h3_length !=''
    ) AS min_text_h3_length, 
    SUM(post_text_h3_length_characters_without_spaces) AS text_h3_length_characters_without_spaces, 
    MAX(post_text_h3_length_characters_without_spaces) AS max_text_h3_length_characters_without_spaces, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(post_text_h3_length_characters_without_spaces) 
        FROM $table_name_posts 
        WHERE post_text_h3_length_characters_without_spaces !=''
    ) AS min_text_h3_length_characters_without_spaces, 
    SUM(post_text_h3_length_characters) AS text_h3_length_characters, 
    MAX(post_text_h3_length_characters) AS max_text_h3_length_characters, 
    (
        SELECT MIN(post_text_h3_length_characters) 
        FROM $table_name_posts 
        WHERE post_text_h3_length_characters !=''
    ) AS min_text_h3_length_characters
FROM $table_name_posts
WHERE (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'draft' OR post_status = 'future')
GROUP BY post_type, post_status
ORDER BY word_count DESC;
```

The problem with grouping a subquery, when choosing MIN, selects the minimum value at all, does not work out GROUP BY post_type, post_status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a mixing of aggreagted  column and subquery yuo  should use conditional aggregation for filter the rows  you need  and avoid subquery
in this way you can use the group by without conflict  with the difference aggreagation level related to subquery

```
SELECT post_type
    , post_status
    , COUNT(post_id) AS posts
    , SUM(post_word_count) AS word_count
    , SUM(post_tag_p_count) AS text_p_count
    , SUM(post_text_p_length) AS text_p_length
    , MAX(post_text_p_length) AS max_text_p_length


    , MIN (CASE WHEN post_text_p_length !='' THEN post_text_p_length ELSE 100000 END) AS min_text_p_length

    , SUM(post_text_p_length_characters_without_spaces) AS text_p_length_characters_without_spaces
    , MAX(post_text_p_length_characters_without_spaces) AS max_text_p_length_characters_without_spaces

    , MIN( CASE WHEN post_text_p_length_characters_without_spaces !='' THEN post_text_p_length_characters_without_spaces ELSE 100000 END)AS min_text_p_length_characters_without_spaces

    , SUM(post_text_p_length_characters) AS text_p_length_characters
    , MAX(post_text_p_length_characters) AS max_text_p_length_characters


    , MIN( CASE WHEN post_text_p_length_characters !='' THEN post_text_p_length_characters ELSE 100000 END ) AS min_text_p_length_characters
    .....
    ....
    , MIN ( CASE WHEN  post_text_h3_length_characters !='' THEN post_text_h3_length_characters ELSE 100000 END)
FROM $table_name_posts
WHERE (post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'draft' OR post_status = 'future')
GROUP BY post_type, post_status
ORDER BY word_count DESC";
```

Where 100000 is just a dummy value for avoid min  for null values in  the case match

Comment: Interesting solution, thanks for the help. Unfortunately I can’t put +